# Where does Thunderbird store archived IMAP emails?

Tags: filesystem, thunderbird

I am using Thunderbird to read my gmail and yahoo emails. Both using IMAP. Then in the *Synchronization & Storage* option of the account, I tick the check-box with the message: Keep messages for this account on this computer.

So, where on my filesystem does Thunderbird store these archived messages?

P.S. I have the `~/.mozilla` and `~/.thunderbird` folders in my home directory.

Comment: there. I detailed.

Comment: thanks for the edits. We were editing each othere there for a moment.

Comment: I thought so, but all's well that ends well! :)

Comment: right you are. cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you didn't change the default profile, Thunderbird will save imap accounts in `~/.thunderbird/something.default/ImapMail` and Directories there for your different accounts.

Anyways, you can have a look in `~/.thunderbird/profiles.ini` under `[Profile0]` to see the path it is using for your profile.

LocalFolders and Pop accounts are in `~/.thunderbird/something.default/Mail` directory.

Comment: Great and complete answer. cheers

Comment: Happy this helped!

Answer (score 1):

In ubuntu ,
open your Home directory and press Ctrl +H to show hidden files in this directory .
You will found .thunderbird in which you will get all files related to your mail .